# how to stop and restart nodes in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nodes, kubectl

i have 3 nodes
`kubectl get nodes`

```
NAME      STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
a1       Ready    master   133m   v1.18.6-gke.6600
a2       Ready    master   132m   v1.18.6-gke.6600
a3       Ready    master   132m   v1.18.6-gke.6600
```

so the status of that nodes is Ready I want to stop first node and again restart that nodes

i tried with

`kubectl cordon a1`

```
NAME      STATUS                     ROLES    AGE    VERSION
a1     Ready,SchedulingDisabled   master   138m   v1.18.6-gke.6600
a2     Ready                      master   137m   v1.18.6-gke.6600
a3     Ready                      master   137m   v1.18.6-gke.6600
```

but my backend is still working and although if icordon all the nodes in that case also my backend is working i want my backend service will be stop and again resume
i also tried with

`kubectl drain a1`

```
error: unable to drain node "abm-cp2", aborting command...

There are pending nodes to be drained:
 a2
error: cannot delete DaemonSet-managed Pods (use --ignore-daemonsets to ignore): kube-system/anetd-4pr9j, kube-system/etcd-defrag-8fs99, kube-system/kube-proxy-8cgpf, kube-system/localpv-mlfnf, kube-system/metallb-speaker-ljsdv, kube-system/node-exporter-dfrnq, kube-system/stackdriver-log-forwarder-t5s88
```

Answer (score 8):

May you are getting the wrong meaning of **cordon** and **drain** node.

**Cordon node** :

it means no more **new** container will get the **scheduled** on this **node** however existing running container will be kept on that same node.

**Drain node** :

The drain node will remove all the containers from that specific node and schedule all the containers to another node.

As much as I under what you want do is

> I want to stop first node and again restart those nodes

if you can access the Node and do the SSH into worker nodes you can also run inside node after SSH : `systemctl restart kubelet`

**OR**

you can stop or scale down the deployment to zero mean you can pause or restart the container or pod

with node you can delete node and new will will join the Kubernetes cluster.

```
kubectl delete node a1
```

which will be similar to restarting the node in this case you must be using the node pools in GKE or AWS other cloud providers.

**Note** : if you are running single replicas of you application you might face the downtime if delete the node or restart the **kubelet**

i would suggest you to **cordon** and **drain** node before you **restart**.

1. `kubectl cordon a1` (stop new pod sceduling)
2. `kubectl drain a1` (remove running containers)
3. `kubectl delete node a1` (remove the node from cluster) or `systemctl restart kubelet` (restart the node)

Regarding the error :

> There are pending nodes to be drained:  a2 error: cannot delete
> DaemonSet-managed Pods

You need to use the `--ignore-daemonsets` key when you drain Kubernetes nodes:

```
--ignore-daemonsets=false: Ignore DaemonSet-managed pods.
```

so command will be something like

```
kubectl drain node <node-name> --ignore-daemonsets
```

Comment: if i use kubectl delete node a1 then it will be deleted then how can i access this again

Comment: either you add the new node to node pool or new will auto spin if managed node pool are there if you don't want to do it just restart the service of kubelet.

Comment: yes a1 nodes is deleted but now if i want to access this again i restarted service of kubectl but nothing happed

Comment: if you can access the VM you can stop the Vm and restart only. you can not access the delete node again you have to add new node. you must be managing the node using the node pool so  deleting pod from pool and adding one is option.

Comment: kubectl drain abm-cp1 --ignore-daemonsets
node/abm-cp1 already cordoned
error: unable to drain node "abm-cp1", aborting command...

There are pending nodes to be drained:
 abm-cp1
error: cannot delete Pods with local storage (use --delete-emptydir-data to override): anthos-identity-service/ais-59bd464ddd-sqhsp, gke-system/istio-ingress-5c6fc44c76-784ls, gke-system/istio-ingress-5c6fc44c76-db7dm, gke-system/istiod-5978f9f749-2675k, gke-system/istiod-5978f9f749-9zc95 it is showing something like this